# Local array inside Heap object - C++

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks

For the purpose of the example - I have a few classes:

```
class RGB {
    short value[3];
};

class AbstractImage {
    protected:
        int n_pixels;

    public:
        virtual ~AbstractImage() {};
}

template <typename T> class Image : public AbstractImage {
    T* data;

    public:
    Image<T>(int n) { n_pixels=n; data=new T[n_pixels]; }
    virtual ~Image<T>() {delete[] data;}

    // also provided is a copy constructor and assignment operator overloading

};
typedef class Image<RGB> ColorImage;
```

Is there a memory leak from Image? Do I need to release the RGB objects one by one with delete? Or isn't there a leak?

From my understanding: data points to content created on the heap (using the word "new") which holds an RGB object array with a size of n_pixels (which has an array called "value" with 3 cells - also on the heap). Which means that we need to delete each object one by one.

Comment: The main rule of dynamic allocation: only `delete` what you `new`.

Comment: I would recommend using a `std::vector` instead, but no there's no leak in your current code. You might have *other* problems due to not following [the rules of three, five or zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), but no leaks.

Comment: You must `delete` exactly what you `new` once. You are not obeying [the rule of zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) so you will have double deletes. If you had used `std::vector` this wouldn't have happened.

Comment: @nwp: The code says that there is assignment op and copy ctor defined. If we take it at its word, and assume that they are correctly implemented, there are no double frees here. Rule of zero would be better of course, but your assertion seems baseless.

Comment: If you _really_ don't want to use `std::vector`, at least use `std::unique_ptr`, which prevents all leaks by default

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a memory leak from Image?

No. You match your `new[]` with `delete[]`. Though of course, it may leak if you leak the containing `Image` object, and never destroy *it*. Your inclusion of a virtual destrcutor (which I presume means you `delete` pointers to `AbstractImage`) ensure the most derived class cleans up after itself.

> Do I need to release the RGB objects one by one with delete?

No, since you didn't allocate any of them individually with `new`. Each and every member of your dynamically allocated array lies in the allocated block. It's default initialized when you allocate the array, and then has its destructor called when you `delete[]` the entire array. The language specification has it covered.

Having said all that, if you need to manage a buffer of objects, using `std::vector` is almost always the superior alternative.

Comment: "it may leak if you leak the containing Image object, and never destroy it" - How might that be implemented?

Comment: `new ColorImage(10);` - That allocates and leaks the `ColorImage` in one statement. But you ask the wrong question. The correct question is "how do I avoid it". That takes special care, and is a subject for entire papers about C++ resource management.

Comment: I had an exam where I was asked if there is a memory leak and i believed there is - mainly due to the fact we have no idea how the code is used. Your example gave me grounds for my answer. Is it also possible to have a leak if the "value" array is reallocated dynamically?

Comment: @AdamMorad - if the reallication is buggy and/or not exception safe, certainly. But I assumed the copy c'tor and co. You mentioned are implemented correctly.

Comment: `Image<T>(const Image<T>& rhs) {
        n_pixels = rhs.n_pixels;
        data = new T[n_pixels];
        copyData(rhs);
}

Image<T>& operator=(const Image<T>& rhs){
    n_pixels = rhs.n_pixels;
    delete[] data;
    data = new T[n_pixels];
    copyData(rhs);
    return *this;
}

void copyData(const Image<T>& rhs) {
    for(int i=0; i<n_pixels;i++) {
        data[i] = rhs.data[i];
    }
}`

Comment: @AdamMorad - I apologize if I misspoke, but my previous comment wasn't a suggestion to review your code. Let alone the misshapen mess posting in comments make of it. Writing exception safe code is something [books can be written about](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/xc++.htm). It's not something to be tutored about in comments or in forums. It takes dedication to grasp, and lots of your mistakes along the way.